# Django REST Framework: error [ "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str." ]

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm getting the following error when trying to post `multipart/form-data` with both a `FileField` and `ManyToManyRelationship` for the `ManyToMany` domains field.

```
[ "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str." ]
```

My serializer is as follows:

```
class DatasetStorePointerCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    domains = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Domain.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = DatasetStorePointer
        fields = [
            'name', 'description', 'supplementary_information', 'type', 'file_entity', 'domains', 'citations', 'owner'
        ]
```

So my serializer is expecting an Array of IDs such as [1,2] but in the `request.data` the Array of domains is going up as `'domains': ['1,2']` ...but it should be `'domains': [1,2]`

N.B. The payload object being sent up is `new FormData()`, where I am taking a Javascript object as parsing it to FormData as follows:

```
    getFormData(object) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      Object.keys(object).forEach(key => formData.append(this.camelToUnderscore(key), object[key]));
      return formData;
    },
```

Does anyone know the fix for this?

Comment: which field is causing the error

Comment: @ArakkalAbu 'domains' field. It should be either ['1', '2'] or [1, 2] but *not* ['1,2']...